# Hide Gitlab Access Tokens Used in Scheduled Jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, access-token, gitlab-api

In my Gitlab Repo, I have to run a scheduled JOB which triggers a Pipeline. And this pipeline deletes the old JOB Logs using Gitlab API.

But this API calls needs the Gitlab AccessToken to perform the operation. Initially I though of using CI_JOB_TOKEN variable, which is auto-generated token, but it has no access to Gitlab APIs.

Alternatively I can store Project AccessToken as a Variable in my Schedule Job. But it will be visible to other people also in Project with Maintainer or Owners roles.

Is there any other way, where either I can store my tokens without reveling it to others? Or some mechanism where I can make it run without passing my Project AccessTokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to store the secret in a vault/cloud service, such as HashiCorp Vault, AWS Secrets Manager, Azure Vault, etc. GitLab has the `CI_JOB_JWT_V2` token, which can be used to [authenticate to cloud services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/index.html). With this method, you do not need to store any secrets in GitLab at all.

You can also see the [Vault integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/) as another option.

The only other option might be to use a runner that has the secret on the system and lock that runner to your project.